# why Safari always GET status 200, never 304 for my .swf file?

Tags: apache-http-server, htaccess

I serve a Flash app as a .swf file (with HTML wrapper file), and Safari always retrieves with GET `status = 200`, never `304`. Thus, Safari never uses cache for this file and downloads it each time (it's a big file).

When I inspect Safari's cache, it never appears to contain the .swf file.

Chrome, Firefox, and IE all use the cache fine (e.g 2nd visit to site returns `status 304`).

If I use a cache manifest for the swf file, Safari does store/retrieve from offline cache, but my customers won't allow the file to be stored in anything but the standard cache, so it's not a solution (although, perhaps useful for debugging?).

Do other people experience this, or is it just me?

Any idea what I can do to make Safari cache correctly?

Comment: Sanity check: Does the swf file fit in safari's browser cache?

Comment: Those statuses aren't from Safari, they're from your server. So the real question here is, "why is my server returning 200 instead of 304 to Safari?" or maybe "How are Safari's requests for this file different from other browsers, that is causing my server to respond differently?". Show us the full headers of a request/response from Safari vs from another browser.